# C# TPL application stops running

Tags: c#

I have an application that was working and has a loop with a variable number of iterations.  I have one function call in this loop.  I then tried to change the program to launch the function as a separate thread.  I set up a unit test to run, and the application stops running before completing any work.

I have set the loop to have one iteration and debug on the one thread.  It stops running near the top of the function, not always on the same line, but in the same area where I try to make a copy of an object that has a data table and data rows where the selection can be changed in each thread.  The following is the code and it consistently stops when debugging in this area, but the line that is reached varies.

```
// main thread called by unit test
...
for(...
{
   Task compute = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => results.Add(Compute(originalObject)));
}
...
private ReturnObject Compute(MyObject originalObject)
{
   ...
   // near top of function after some assignment statements
   // of some string and boolean variables
   MyObject myObject = originalObject.Copy;
   // never makes it to the next line
   ...
}

// MyObject class

private MyObject(DataTable dtTable)
{
   _dataService = new DataService();
   _dataTable = dtTable.Copy();
   _dataRows = _dataTable.Select();
}

public MyObject Copy()
{
   MyObject copy = new MyObject(_dtTable);
   return copy;
}

// DataService class

public DataService()
{
   _oleDbConnection = null;
}
```

Comment: What does the entry point look like? My guess is that this is a console app, which will end as soon as the entry point code is done. But, that is just a guess without seeing the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not appear to `Wait` for the tasks that you create to complete: you must either call the `Wait` method or access the `Result` property of a generic task to block the calling thread until the work is complete, try the following:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
for ...
{
   Task compute = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => results.Add(Compute(originalObject)));
   tasks.Add(compute);
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```